# How to disable auto play MP3 files?

Tags: 10.04, gnome

When I put my mouse/cursor over an MP3 file, a few seconds later the music/file starts playing. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- In a Nautilus window, Goto **Edit>>Preferences** and then goto Preview tab and then in Preview sound files select **Never**.

  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I have many MP3 files on my desktop and sometimes it starts playing the songs and is very annoying! I always forget this preferences menu, I always look at the System menu.